# URL not resolved with APIView in Django REST Framework for non-model end point

Tags: django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to create a non-model API endpoint, but I'm a having a bit of trouble setting it up. Below is my code.

`views.py`

```
from rest_framework import views, viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response

from myproject.apps.policies.models import Customer
from .serializers import CustomerSerializer


class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer


class CalculateQuoteView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Just a random test.')
        return Response({"success": True, "content": "Hello World!"})
```

My `url.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .policies import views as policies_views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('policies', policies_views.CustomerViewSet)
#urlpatterns = router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^quote/', policies_views.CalculateQuoteView.as_view()),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Using curl for testing:

`curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/quote/ -H 'Authorization: Token 8636c43eb7a90randomtokenhere5c76555e93d3'`

I get the following output:

`{"detail":"Not found."}`

Basically, in the end I will need to pass in details to the `quote` API endpoint and get some response data. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what is the status code? does this print `print('Just a random test.')` executes while requesting?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: Nope. I'm getting the following: `Not Found: /api/v1/policies/quote/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should query:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8000/api/v1/quote/
```

or alter the urls as:

```
url(r'^policies/quote/', policies_views.CalculateQuoteView.as_view()),
```